# Preventing mysqladmin proc from messing up my terminal

Tags: mysql, sed

We do a lot of queries with binary data in them, and because of that, sometimes when I run "mysqladmin proc", my terminal gets messed up.  Running reset fixes it, but I'd prefer to just prevent the problem in the first place.  How can I strip these out with sed?  Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe to `cat -v` (should show "non-printing" characters in escaped notation)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g' inputfile
```